# How to stop javascript from formatting numbers?

Tags: javascript, math

When you run a huge  sum in JS it comes out with something like : `1.0328135768135768e+21`.
Is there a way to make it output a pure integer, even if it is very long?

Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't, if the number is outside the integer range, like in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.toString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) seems to do the trick. Sort of:

```
1.0328135768135768e+21.toString("10");
// "1032813576813576802460"

1.0328135768135768e+50.toString("10")
// "103281357681357664662886440420862446808642642662440"
```

Note that (as shown above) because of JS's handling of floating point numbers you don't just get the digits you specified with zeros on the end.

If you wanted all zeros on the end you could always format it yourself:

```
function formatNumber(n) {
    var s = n + "",
        a = s.split("e");
    if (a.length === 1)
        return s;
    s = a[0].replace(/\./,"");
    s += (new Array(+a[1] - s.length + 2).join("0"));
    return s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HLQQ9/ (Note: *not* tested thoroughly at all, just a half-baked idea I hacked together to give you a starting point.)

Or there are several [big number](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) libraries around.